# when can't methods of undetermined coefficient be used in this case

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have solved the equation $y'' +3y'+2y= \frac{1}{1+e^{x}}$ and I have solved through varation of parameters.

However there is an addendum to the question I was asked, and that was, why can't methods of undetermined coefficient be used to solved this?

I am at a loss for how to start to answer this, or the reasons why variation breaks down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, undetermined coefficients can be used when the derivatives of the source term terminate in some useful way, either by going to zero (polynomials) or by going into some kind of loop. (exponentials, sine and cosine)

Here the derivatives will never fall into one of these nice patterns and we will never be able to make a form for $y_p$ which includes every derivative.

Comment: thank you for the succinct answer